# Notify threads to do work, and know when complete

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have the following task I want to do. I want to launch a thread manager / pool, that should launch all the threads and wait until there is work to be done. Then I should signal the threads to do work, and i should receive a signal back when it is all complete. I have implemented it below, but it does not seem to work.

```
class ThreadManager{
public:
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::vector<bool> threadCompletes;

    std::mutex sendMtx, recvMtx;
    std::condition_variable sendCv;

    static void thread_worker(int id, ThreadManager* manager){
        while(1){
            cout << "Thread Wait: " << id << endl;
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(manager->sendMtx);
            manager->sendCv.wait(lck);
            **lck.unlock();** # JUST ADDED THIS
            // DO WORK
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
            manager->threadCompletes[id] = true;
            bool done = (std::find(std::begin(manager->threadCompletes), std::end(manager->threadCompletes), false) == std::end(manager->threadCompletes));
            cout << "Job Complete: " << id << endl;
            if(done){
                cout << "All Done" << endl;
                manager->recvMtx.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    ThreadManager(){

    }

    void addThread(){
        threadCompletes.push_back(false);
        threads.push_back(std::thread(ThreadManager::thread_worker, threads.size(), this));
    }

    void signal(){
        for(auto i : threadCompletes) i = 0;
        recvMtx.lock();
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> sendLck(sendMtx);
        sendCv.notify_all();
    }

    void wait(){
        recvMtx.lock();
        recvMtx.unlock();
    }

    void join(){
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i) {
            threads[i].join();
        }
    }
};


void test2(){

    ThreadManager manager;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        manager.addThread();
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

    manager.signal();
    manager.wait();
    cout << "Complete" << endl;

    manager.join();

}
```

What happens is that the threads all launch and block on the wait call, and when I signal it, each thread seems to only run subsequently.

```
Thread Wait: 0
Thread Wait: 1
Thread Wait: 2
Thread Wait: 3
Thread Wait: 4
Job Complete: 0
Thread Wait: 0
Job Complete: 1 # Done one after the other 500ms
Thread Wait: 1
Job Complete: 2 # Done one after the other 500ms
Thread Wait: 2
Job Complete: 3 # Done one after the other 500ms
Thread Wait: 3
Job Complete: 4 # Done one after the other 500ms
All Done
Thread Wait: 4
Complete
```

What am i doing wrong

**EDIT:**

I have added the unlock flag. However, now if I do something like this, it eventually fails:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    manager.signal();
    manager.wait();
    cout << "Complete" << endl;
}

cout << "ALL DONE" << endl;
```

Basically, it runs to "Complete" 2 or 3 times, but it never reaches "ALL DONE". There is some other race condition going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each thread locks the same mutex for most of their lifetime, including around a sleep-for-500ms operation, which can only begin once the thread has obtained the mutex. This effectively prevents concurrency and makes the multi-threading useless.

I don't understand the purpose of having a sleep in the worker threads at all but, if there is one, move it to outside of the mutex lock. Do that by unlocking as soon as the condition variable has woken; you don't need it locked any more; that'll free up the other threads to get to work concurrently.

Comment: Hold on, so what is the correct way to actually do this. Are you talking about the sendMutex?

Comment: Yes, `manager->sendMtx`. You should hold locks for the minimum duration necessary, only.

Comment: I think you want to unlock as soon as the condition variable has woken. And review how condition variables should be used - think you need a loop around that wait call.

Comment: so i just unlock the lock after "manager->sendCv.wait(lck);" ?

Comment: That's my suggestion yes. But I propose you give it a bit more thought and find examples on using condition variables

Comment: I have edited my question with another extending issue. I tried calling my signal and wait in a loop, and after a few loops, it hangs. I can't figure out why also. It also happens with just 1 loop

Comment: One question per question please. Again, research how to use condition variables properly. There are loads of explanations and examples online and in your C++ multithreading book. No way you already did it in the last 9 minutes

Comment: Thanks I have solved the problem. I needed a mutex between my threadCompletes variable

Comment: My bad that does not work either, I suppose I could move it to another question

Comment: You could, but only after _doing some research_.